# How to hide a specific category displays with products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: product image from shop page]

How can i hide a specific product category on the shop and home page?

This is how it is looks like from browser

```
<div class="wd-product-cats">
                <a href="https://new.uniques.lk/product-category/for-him/" rel="tag">For Him</a>, 
          <a href="https://new.uniques.lk/product-category/hot-new/" rel="tag">New</a>      
</div>
```

Actually, i can hide the word "new" using the following CSS, but don't know how to remove "," after the first category (For Him).

```
.wd-product-cats a[href="https://new.uniques.lk/product-category/hot-new/"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css for hide any char.

Data: This is some random data.
like that :-
in this css i am hiding word "Data:"

h4 { position: relative; background-color: white; }

h4:before { content: "Data: "; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: white; color: white; }

Comment: <h4>Data: This is some random data.</h4>